# Make a list from the words of fileA and check with that list Against fileB in python

Tags: python, list, replace

With a bit more detail, i have a list of common words in a txt file and i want to check if any of those words (around 2000) exist in another file (html) and if they do replace them with a constant string (sssss for example). Regex didn't help me much using either of these `\b  \b(?:one|two|three)\b or \w or ?:^|(?<= ))(one|common|word|or|another)(?:(?= )|$)` .

Now i know how to open a file and import the first list but i don't know how to check every entry of that list against a huge text and replace their instances. I don't mind if it would take time I just really need this done and don't know how.

```
import re
import string

f = open('test2.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
print (lines)
```

Comment: Are you storing the html text as a single string? Are you only replacing strictly text in the html?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @rahlf23 I wasn't sure on how to store it and yes nothing else

Comment: @Prune its not time i need because i have scoured the internet for the last two days looking into similar stuff so i can have some insight into it but its like no one ever needed to replace that many (2000+ ) words (which could have 30k instances in the file) with a single word

Comment: I suggested the time because your lack of progress suggests that you need tutelage on several language facilities and perhaps looping applications.  From what you've written so far, it appears that a straightforward loop, plus the `any` and/or `replace` functions will cover what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for you. Parse each file into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) where each word would be an entry.

Then you can do a comparison between both sets with one of the aggregation functions: [`union`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union), [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference), or [`symmetric difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference).

Regular expressions is not necessary unless you plan to make additional correlations with each word (comparing `cat` to `cats`). But if you plan to go down this road, then you're probably better off generating a [Trie (prefix tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). I can expand more if you are willing to show some more code (progress).